# SSH - identify which users still login using passwords

Tags: ssh

I have an Ubuntu Linux server allowing password authentication for SSH, and I want to switch it to SSH keys only and disable password login.

Before I disable password login, how can I find out which users are still using passwords, and which have switched to key authentication?

Comment: Btw., while many people don't know that, you can also ask for key *and* serverside password. A bit more bothersome, but of course more secure too, if you do that...

Comment: Disable password login without notice and see how many people scream.

Comment: @Mark: [If a user screams in frustration, but they're logging in remotely so you don't hear it, will you still get an angry email?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest)

Comment: @deviantfan It would be more secure to simply require a longer [keyfile](https://serverfault.com/a/822583/85654), but that would require a bit of scripting.

Comment: @jpaugh In terms of entropy, likely (but, how about a longer keyfile and a password? :)). But, what a keyfile of any length never will be, a second independent factor. Think of eg. a stolen keyfile, of any length, without server-side password ...  and there's rate-limiting, logging, etc. on the server. ... (Keyfile passphrases are, in comparison to the password, pretty useless: either quickly cracked with all the GPU power the attacker can throw onto it because there's no rate limiting, or it is a "key" itself which can't be remembered by the user and has to be stored somewhere again...)

Comment: Are you using pam as the underlying authentication mechanism? You can configure it for example by installing a plugin that can run a script that logs stuff and have it log password based logins (I do something slightly similar by logging all passwords for nonexistent accounts on a honeypot like machine)

Comment: @deviantfan I take your point. But, you're assuming the password for the private key is different than the one for the server; (whereas, I'm assuming the private key file *has* a password, I know.)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't do that 100% reliably, but there are two strong indications:

- First, the presence of a `.ssh/authorized_keys` file is a hint the user is at least prepared to use key based login
- Second, in the authentication log file (`/var/log/secure` on CentOS, `/var/log/auth.log` on Debian/Ubuntu), the auth method will be logged:

  ```
  Sep 28 13:44:28 hostname sshd[12084]: Accepted publickey for sven
  ```

  vs

  ```
  Sep 28 13:47:36 hostname sshd[12698]: Accepted password for sven
  ```

  Scan the log for entries with password mentioned to learn who is still using passwords. This will not work with users seldom logging in of course unless you have very long log retention.

Comment: by 'Scan' the log file,  I presume you mean sensible options such as using grep? `grep 'password' /var/log/ssh/sshd.log`

Comment: @djsmiley2k: Yes, exactly. Or whatever other method you prefer for that task.

Comment: Isn't the first method thwarted by proper security practices, such as `700` permissions on the user's `.ssh` directory, and root squash on mounted home directories?

Comment: @OgrePsalm33: You can do this search on the NFS *server* ...

Comment: If "proper security practices" are being followed, there is no NFS. NFS is a gaping hole.

Comment: Also if `.ssh` is mode `0700`, I'm pretty sure the user won't be able to login at all. The `sshd` process has to read these files *before* authenticating the user and it probably does not `setuid` down to the user before authenticating them. BTW this is also a way to work around the (idiotic, nonsensical, useless) "root squashing" on NFS: just write a program that runs as root and cycles through each user with `seteuid` to read their files.

Comment: @R..: You can get NFS reasonably secure with NFSv4 and Kerberos (in which case key based login gets complicated ). Other than that: Yes, key based login works without any issues when `~/.ssh` is set to `700` and in root squashed NFS home directories, so it clearly has to switch user ids at least for key based auth to read `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Was going to say, my `.ssh` dir is 700 *right now* (and has been for years), and I can still log in with my SSH key, so yeah, I know this works.  We recently witnessed had an audit on a system, and the "tester" was able to find a user with a 777 directory, who had sudo and, combined with no root squash on the home dirs, they were able to pwn the whole system.  Needless to say, security has been tightened on that system!  Hence the reason I asked.

Answer (score 19):

Fastest way is to disable it and see who knocks on your office door ;p

Comment: This is not the fastest way, because not every user might login every day, while the logs can clearly show when someone logged in, so they give an instant result

Comment: This is the slowest way. People only login to the server if their application is down. It could take years for that to happen.

Comment: @pete you are the top :)